# Flappy Bird Clones :)

Tags: code-golf, game

Everyone's been freaking out about that stupid "Flappy Bird" game being removed. So, your task is to crate a Flappy Bird Clone game. Its really simple. Here are the guide lines:

- It can use either ascii art or real images
- You can make your "bird" flap with either a click or a key press
- It should try to be as short as possible, hence the [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) tag.

Here's an example: http://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/1xiimx/i_couldnt_sleep_so_i_cloned_your_flappy_bird/

In order to be a "Flappy Bird Clone," your game needs to have the following:

- A bird, or other character
- The "bird" should move slightly up when a key is pressed or you click/tap
- If there is no clicking/tapping/etc, the "bird" should rapidly move downwards
- Pipes or other obstacles should move leftwards on the screen, creating the illusion that the bird is moving
- The pipes should have a small gap for the bird to fly through.
- Every time you pass through a gap between pipes, your score increases by 1.
- If you hit a pipe or the ground, the game ends and your score is displayed.

It doesn't really need to be a "bird" or a "pipe," it can all be ascii. Here's a very minimal example of a flappy bird screen:

```
/-----[4]-----\
| ||      ||  |
| ||      ¯¯  |
| ||  O>      |
| ¯¯      __  |
| __      ||  |
| ||      ||  |
\-------------/
```

Comment: A question should ideally be self-contained, and should certainly contain at least a broad-brush spec.

Comment: As it stands, there appears to be a little too much subjectivity in what's considered a valid submission

Comment: There. I put some guidelines as to makes up a "flappy bird clone"

Comment: I did this a couple weeks ago. Maybe I'll golf it when I get some time: http://cwhart.co/nyanpybird/

Comment: I _really_ _really_ want to see an ASCII art version!

Comment: @SuperScript Checkout my answer... http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/23556/4178

Comment: Wait, really? Flappy bird got removed?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Javascript+jQuery (ASCII Art) - <del>571</del> <del>524</del> <del>491</del> 464

```
l=$('[id$=52] h4~pre').click(()=>{m=1}),o=[],d=0,e=4,m=1;setInterval(()=>{t=Array(153);s=~~(d/10-0.99);d++;d%10?0:o[d+20]=~~(Math.random()*5)+1;for(i=-1;k=o[i+d],i<17;i++)if(k--)for(j=-1;c=j==k||j-k==4?'-':j-k>0&&j-k<4?0:'|',j<9;j++)i>-1?t[j*17+i]=c:0,i<16?t[j*17+i+1]=c:0;m-=.2;e-=m;if(e<0||e>10||t[~~e*17+8])e=4,m=1,d=0,o=[];t[~~e*17+8]='>';r='|-------['+s+']-------';for(i=0;z=t[i]||' ',i<153;i++)i%17?r+=z:r+='|\n|'+z;r+='|\n|-----------------|';l.html(r);},150)
```

> ##### Demo
>
> Open the dev tools console (F12) and run the above code in **this page** to use the below demo (right now, go ahead!):
>
> ```
> |-------[5]-------|
> |    ||        -- |
> |    ||           |
> |    ||           |
> |    --           |
> |              -- |
> |              || |
> |              || |
> |    --  >     || |
> |    ||        || |
> |-----------------|
> ```

Known minor bugs:

- If you get a double-digit score, it messes up the layout
- It is NOT easy!!! (but the original wasn't either)
- There's a tradeoff between efficiency and golfedness

Feel free to comment with your highscore.

Also, this is my first Code Golf post, so suggestions on compression, etc. will be welcomed

Comment: You can remove `var` keyword and variable declaration. You can also replace `Array(153)` by `[]` and probably can replace `~~(Math.random()*5)+1` by `1+new Date%5`

Comment: If you ignore the layout, skip jQuery and add the HTML it is 416 bytes: http://jsbin.com/flap/1/edit?html,output

Comment: Scored 17. I have no life, I know.

Comment: `Known_minor_bugs += "irritating, unwanted and distracting text selections when double clicking";`

Comment: This is apparently really addicting for some reason. I got a 19

Answer (score 23):

### Javascript + jQuery (997)

*Tested on Chrome 32, Firefox 27, IE9*

Open Console (F12) from **this** page and copy/paste the following code.

```
scroll(0,0);h=1/30;p=[];r=320;n=0;w=80;f=2.5;o=80;t=setInterval;$('#question').children().hide().end().append('<p id="m"></p>').append('<p id="s"></p>').click(function(){v=100});$('#s').css({position:'relative',margin:'auto',border:'2px solid',width:200,height:r}).append('<img id="b" src="//i.imgur.com/4w6Vgud.gif"/>');$('<style>.p{width:1px;border:1px solid;position:absolute}</style>').appendTo('head');function u(){$('#m').text('score '+m+' (max '+n+')')}function i(){x=r/2;v=0;m=0;p.length=0;u()}i();t("v-=h*100;x+=h*v;if(x<0||x>r)i();$('.p').remove();for(j=0;j<p.length;j++){p[j].r+=h*w;if(p[j].r>200){p.shift();j--;m++;if(m>n)n=m;u();}else if((p[j].r>165&&p[j].r<185)&&(x<p[j].h||x>p[j].h+o))i();else{$('<div class=p></div>').appendTo('#s').css({bottom:0,right:p[j].r,height:p[j].h});$('<div class=p></div>').appendTo('#s').css({bottom:p[j].h+o,right:p[j].r,height:320-p[j].h-o})}}$('#b').css({position:'absolute',left:0,bottom:x-25})",h*1e3);t("p.push({h:Math.random()*(r-o),r:0})",f*1e3)
```

> [image]
>   *The game replace the question block of this page.*
>   *You have to click on the game frame to make the bird fly.*

Ungolfed and commented version :

```
$('#question').children().hide();
$('#question').append('<div id="score"></div>');
$('#question').append('<div id="scene"></div>');
$('#scene').css({position:'relative',margin:'auto',border:'2px solid black',width:'200',height:'320'});
$('#scene').append('<img id="bird" src="http://fc01.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2014/037/d/0/pixel_art___flappy_bird_by_hipsterli-d75dkyr.gif"></img>');
$('#bird').css({display:'block',position:'absolute',left:0,'pointer-events':'none',margin:'0 auto'});
$(window).scrollTop(0);

//CONFIGURATION
var dt=1/30,      //delta timestep (typically 30Hz)
    pipevel=80,   //pipe velocity (in pixels per second)
    pipefreq=2.5, //pipe spawn frequency (in second)
    holesize=80,  //hole size (in pixels)
    gravity=-100, //gravity (in pixels per square second)
    punchvel=100; //velocity punch when clicked (in pixels per second)

var x, y, pipes=[], roof=$('#scene').height(), score, maxscore=0;

function updateScore() {
  $('#score').text('Score : '+score+' (max : '+maxscore+')');
}

function init() {
  x=roof/2; //position
  v=0; //velocity
  score=0;
  pipes.length=0;

  updateScore();
}

function step() {
  //euler integration
  v+=dt*gravity;
  x+=dt*v;

  if (x<0 || x>roof)  init();

  //pipes
  $('.pipe').remove();
  for (i=0; i<pipes.length; i++) {
    pipes[i].rightpos += dt*pipevel;
    if (pipes[i].rightpos > 200) {
      pipes.shift();
      i--;
      score++;
      if (score>maxscore) maxscore=score;
      updateScore();
    } else if ((pipes[i].rightpos > 165 && pipes[i].rightpos < 185) && (x < pipes[i].holepos || x > pipes[i].holepos+holesize)) {
      //collision
      init();
    } else {
      $('#scene').append('<div class="pipe" style="background-color:#000; width:1px;border:1px solid #000; position:absolute; bottom:0; right:'+Math.floor(pipes[i].rightpos)+'px; height:'+pipes[i].holepos+'px"></div>');
      $('#scene').append('<div class="pipe" style="background-color:#000; width:1px;border:1px solid #000; position:absolute; bottom:'+(pipes[i].holepos+holesize)+'; right:'+Math.floor(pipes[i].rightpos)+'px; height:'+(320-(pipes[i].holepos+holesize))+'px"></div>');
    }
  }

  $('#bird').css({bottom:Math.floor(x)-25});

  setTimeout(step, dt*1000);
}

$('#question').click(function() {
  v=punchvel;
});

function addPipe() {
  pipes.push({holepos:Math.random()*(roof-holesize),rightpos:0});
  setTimeout(addPipe, pipefreq*1000);
}

init();
setTimeout(step, dt*1000);
setTimeout(addPipe, pipefreq*1000);
```

You can easily modify the configuration (gravity, pipe velocity...), have a look at commented version.

Comment: Works fine in Firefox 27 as well. Nicely done +1

Comment: Thanks, works on IE9 too, so I guess it works on any decent browser :)

Comment: nice work :) and like usual on javascript here abusing the question as target :P

Comment: I'm curious: what did you use to develop the script? surely not Console F12 ?!

Comment: @MarkLakata Why not? Chrome devtools is more than capable.

Comment: High score of 14. This game is too hard :(

Comment: Also, change `v=100` to `v+=50` for a more stable control scheme (no character savings, though).

Comment: @MarkLakata, I used the Chrome Console.

Comment: @JoeZ., I have never played to the original flappy bird, I thought there was a velocity limit. But I think my game is too easy compared to the original, the gravity is low and the pipes move slowly.

Comment: With the current control scheme, it's too easy to accidentally misclick and then not be able to fall far enough to get to the next hole (and then being unable to do anything about it).

Comment: @JoeZ. isn't it the goal of the game ? To not misclick ? :)

Comment: What I'm saying is that it's *too easy* to misclick somewhere in the middle, and it's also too hard to click properly because your punch always sets you to the same initial velocity regardless of how fast you've already gone down.

Comment: @JoeZ. ok go it !

Comment: BTW, I found a bug - when you minimize the window for a few seconds and reopen it, you get about 5 walls at once.

Answer (score 6):

### Floppy Dragon, JavaScript, 1024b

I'm making this game for the current js1k compo ( http://js1k.com )

Play: http://js1k.com/2014-dragons/demo/1704

```
_='c.scale(,    ;ontouchH=onmousedown=onkeydowif(e){    }else h=45,d=1};(Eq";Rect(0,0,^,^9Q"-k,0Q+N),0()-k,2E3980-(+3)N(+3)),Y(p="fEFf&{{~_=,;=vviJ.jfVi/.OoyizyhkhEwf74)\\n$fwwuvtU`"+(10<h?"iZ[*)yj:*im**y|Ktdww54#5Dy\\iz[Kzi[Jiijk[e@1!":"zl]LfU{\\lKtBUh{zzU66iigig5\\n&iiyz{vfwwiyDfwiiE"0"v=i-e,w=(j-=h)-eG in p)y=8>>4),z=16&15),Iv+=e?y:z,w+=e?-z:y(dW(h-=6dW!eW(k+=Q,^<kW(k-=^)!dXeX(k+280)%8X(f++,Q<lWl--if(q>jX9q<jX!((k+3)%8)W(j<qXj>2q))e=40;fff";c.font="6em Arial";dWf1,5dX"#FloppyDragon"11,5eW"score"4,4e?"reH":d?"":"H"5,6setTimeout(n,l)})()I40*o-k,a.width/()/2-30*    d=e=f=h=0;g=[];G=0;Y>o;o++)=g[o+Y]=8*Math.random()|0;i=j=3;k=Q;l=qc.fill;c.beginPath(c.moveTo(Style="#G=2E3;o--;)o%Q?,a.height/Y1*g[Q*~~(k/8)+Q]+);g[o]-2*(p.charCodeAt(o)Text(00n=function(){4*):(,1*Gfor(oHstartIc.lineTo(N),-4,1*Q20W&&X||Y1E3^4E4q50';for(Y in $='q^YXWQNIHG    ')with(_.split($[Y]))_=join(pop());eval(_)
```

All feedbacks and new ideas are welcome!

Comment: This is even harder than Flappy Bird. It would be easier to play if you made a keypress trigger the flap action, but I realize this is code golf and more features means more code.

Comment: no it's okay, I can try to add keypress support if you think it's useful...

Comment: @crazedgremlin keypress control was added in the latest version ;)

Comment: Cool! I can't get past 10, but it's still cool.

Answer (score 4):

## Color Animation and Physics; Pure JavaScript, 457 (335) bytes

This is my first post in this forum; I made this code and retrospectively found this thread to post it in. 
Here's the code encapsulated in HTML, ready to be copy/pasted in to an html file:

```
<body><script>A=120;B=280;d=document;y=180;x=v=n=s=0;f=140;c=d.createElement('canvas');p=c.getContext('2d');c.width=B;c.height=400;c.onclick=()=>{v-=6};p.font='50px Arial';d.body.appendChild(c);r=(h,t,k=0,i='#0f0',w=40)=>{p.fillStyle=i;p.fillRect(h,k,w,t)};b=setInterval(()=>{if(x==0){n=f;f=Math.floor(B*Math.random());x=160}x--;v+=.1;y+=v;r(0,400,0,'#08f',B);r(20,40,y,'#fc0');r(x-40,n);r(x+A,f);r(x-40,B-n,n+A);r(x+A,B-f,f+A);if(x==60)s++;p.strokeText(s,A,80);if(x>20&&x<100&&(y<n||y>n+80)){clearInterval(b);location.reload()}},15)</script><br>Made by Thomas Kaldahl</body>
```

It has pixel perfect collisions, accurate quadratic physics, and smooth color animations, all in 457 bytes worth of purely independent offline Javascript code, shown ungolfed here in greater detail and explanation:

```
<!--entire HTML shell is omitted in golf-->
<body>
    <script>
        //common numbers and the document are assigned shortcut letters
        A = 120;
        B = 280;
        d = document;

        y = 180; //y position of the top of the bird
        x = //x position of scrolling for pipes
        v = //vertical velocity of bird
        n = //y position of the top of the nearest pipe opening
        s = 0; //score
        f = 140; //y position of the top of the farther pipe opening
        c = d.createElement('canvas'); //canvas
        p = c.getContext('2d'); //canvas context
        //set canvas dimensions
        c.width = B;
        c.height = 400;

        c.onclick = () => { v -= 6 }; //apply jump velocity to bird when clicked
        p.font = '50px Arial'; //font for scoring (omitted in golf)
        d.body.appendChild(c); //add canvas to html page
        //draw a rectangle on the canvas
        r = (h, t, k = 0, i = '#0f0', w = 40) => {
            p.fillStyle = i;
            p.fillRect(h, k, w, t)
        };
        //main loop (not assigned to b in golf)
        b = setInterval( () => {
            if (x == 0) { //the x position is a countdown. when it hits 0:
                n = f; //the far pipe is now the near pipe, overwriting the old near pipe
                f = B * Math.random() //assign the far pipe a new vertical location
                x = 160; //restart the countdown back at 160
                //(score increments here in golf)
            }
            x--; //count down
            v += .1; // apply gravity to velocity
            y += v; // apply velocity to bird
            r(0, 400, 0, '#08f', B); //draw background
            r(20, 40, y, '#fc0'); //draw bird (non-default color is omitted in golf)
            r(x - 40, n); //draw first pipe upper half
            r(x + A, f); //draw second pipe upper half
            r(x - 40, B - n, n + A); //draw first pipe lower half
            r(x + A, B - f, f + A); //draw second pipe lower half
            if (x == 60)
                s++; //(this is done earlier on golf)
            p.strokeText(s, A, 80); //draw score
            // if the bird is in range of the pipes horizontally,
            // and is not in between the pipes,
            if (x > 20 && x < 100 && (y < n || y > n + 80)) {
                clearInterval(b); location.reload() //omit interval clear in golf
            }
        }, 15) //(reduced the frame delay to 9, a 1 digit number, in golf)
    </script><br>
    Made by Thomas Kaldahl <!-- GG -->
</body>
```

For fun, here's a 1066 byte version with fancier graphics:

```
<body style='margin:0'><script>var y=180,x=v=n=s=0,f=140,c=document.createElement('canvas'),p=c.getContext('2d');c.width=280;c.height=400;c.onclick=function(){v-=6};c.style='width:68vh;height:97vh';document.body.appendChild(c);p.font="50px Arial";p.shadowColor='#444';p.shadowBlur=9;p.shadowOffsetX=p.shadowOffsetY=5;function r(h,t,k=0,i='#0f0',j='#0a0',u=0,l=0,w=40){var g=p.createLinearGradient(h,l,h+40,u);g.addColorStop(0,i);g.addColorStop(1,j);p.fillStyle=g;p.fillRect(h,k,w,t);}b=setInterval(function(){if(x==0){n=f;f=Math.floor(280*Math.random());}x=x==0?159:x-1;v+=.1;y+=v;r(0,400,0,'#08c','#0cf',280,0,280);r(20,40,y,'#ff0','#fa0',y+40,y);r(x-40,n);r(x-50,20,n-20,'#0f0','#0a0',n+20,n,60);r(x+120,f);r(x+110,20,f-20,'#0f0','#0a0',f+20,f,60);r(x-40,280-n,n+120);r(x-50,20,n+120,'#0f0','#0a0',n+140,n+100,60);r(x+120,280-f,f+120);r(x+110,20,f+120,'#0f0','#0a0',f+140,f+100,60);if(x==60){s++;}p.fillStyle='#fff';p.fillText(s,120,80);if(x>20&&x<100&&(y<n||y>n+80)||y<0||y>360){clearInterval(b);location.reload();}},15);</script><br>Made by Thomas Kaldahl</body>
```

[image]

Also, is it cheating to use a compression system like DEFLATE?
Below is the ASCII85 code for a DEFLATEd version of the code:
By the way, compressed it is 335 bytes total.

Gapon95_Wi'Kf'c(i##6'h,+cM\JZeFO<h;$W'#A1',RqNigBH02C'#R$m]<i<X#6GR`2pE<Ri5mu-n%cVPrsJe:*R^pnr9bI@[DAZnPP02A^!.$MN/@`U7l5gm!!Vr4>A;P?u[Pk8]jCnOP%dIu?`fWql>"tuO4/KbIWgK;7/iJN'f2,hnFg8e.^SO*t\*`,3JBn6j(f`O#],M0;5Sa35Zc@*XaBs@N%]k\M76qa[.ie7n(^*Z5G-lfhUZ3F#'%,X17Pj1u]L)LjpO6XbIl%N3tJhTsab8oV1T(?MC$9mT;90VMmnfBNKEY(^'UV4c?SW':X(!4,*WCY+f;19eQ?`FK0I"(uDe:f&XV&^Rc+'SWRIbd8Lj9bG.l(MRUc1G8HoUsn#H\V(8"Y$/TT(^kATb(OreGfWH7uIf

Comment: This looks great, but unfortunately for [tag:codr-golf] questions we require *golfed* code.

Comment: @NoOneIsHere please _read_ the post and view the golfed code for yourself

Comment: I'm sorry, I see now. This is a great answer.

Answer (score 4):

## C, <s>386</s> <s>351</s> <s>347</s> 341 bytes (Windows, MinGW), 332 with a terminal emulator

[image]

Certainly not the prettiest entry, but it captures the core mechanics of flappy bird: The bird accelerates downwards, pressing a key makes him jump up, touching the pipes or the edges of the screen ends the game, score is the number of cleared pipes.

```
#import<windows.h>
#define T(x)P[v*10+x]=
char P[71];X,Y,W,s;main(v){srand(time(0));for(float y=1,t=0;!(v<0|v>6|(v<Y|v>=Y+W)&X>0&X<3);Sleep(99)){y+=t=kbhit()?getch(),-.9:t+.3;--X<0?X=8,Y=rand()%3+1,W=rand()%2+2:X-1||++s;memset(P,32,70);for(v=0;v<7;T(9)10,T(X)v<Y|v++>=Y+W?35:32);v=y;T(1)79;T(2)62;system("cls");printf("%s\nSCORE: %d",P,s);}}
```

It can be shortened to 333 bytes, if a POSIX terminal emulator is used (like Cmder):

```
#import<windows.h>
#define T(x)P[v*10+x]=
char P[71];X,Y,W,s;main(v){srand(time(0));for(float y=1,t=0;!(v<0|v>6|(v<Y|v>=Y+W)&X>0&X<3);Sleep(99)){y+=t=kbhit()?getch(),-.9:t+.3;--X<0?X=8,Y=rand()%3+1,W=rand()%2+2:X-1||++s;memset(P,32,70);for(v=0;v<7;T(9)10,T(X)v<Y|v++>=Y+W?35:32);v=y;T(1)79;T(2)62;printf("\033c%s\nSCORE: %d",P,s);}}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Objective C - ungolfed

Possibly the worst code I have ever written.

[image: Hacky Bird Running]

You can download the binary here: [AsciiBird Download Binary](http://www.mediafire.com/download/6stxhbzr11ovty3/AsciiBird)

Tap the control key frantically to keep the bird in the air!

This was compiled by Xcode and run in Terminal. It has colors!
Protip: Resize your terminal's window so you don't see a backlog of screen refreshes.

main.m:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "ABManager.h"

void drawScreen(int counter)
{
    __block struct ABPoint thisPoint;
    thisPoint.x = 0;
    thisPoint.y = 0;

    __block ABManager *man = [ABManager sharedManager];
    [man.screen enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *c, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
     {
         NSString *c2 = c;
         NSMutableArray *newObstacles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
         for (NSValue *s in man.obstacles)
         {
             struct ABPoint o;
             [s getValue:&o];

             if (thisPoint.x == o.x)
             {
                 if (thisPoint.y != o.y && thisPoint.y != (o.y + 1) && thisPoint.y != (o.y - 1))
                 {
                     c2 = @"\033[1;33m|\033[0m";
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     if (counter == 0 && thisPoint.y < o.y)
                     {
                         o.x = o.x - 1;

                         if (o.x < 0)
                         {
                             o.x = 49;
                             o.y = (arc4random() % 11) + 1;
                         }

                         if (man.charPos.x == o.x)
                         {
                             man.score = man.score + 1;
                         }
                     }
                 }
             }
             [newObstacles addObject:[NSValue valueWithBytes:&o objCType:@encode(struct ABPoint)]];
         }

         man.obstacles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: newObstacles];


         if (thisPoint.x == man.charPos.x && thisPoint.y == man.charPos.y)
         {
             printf("\033[1;35m>\033[0m");

             if ([c2 isEqualToString:@"\033[1;33m|\033[0m"])
             {
                 man.shouldExit = TRUE;
             }
         }
         else
         {
             printf("%s", [c2 UTF8String]);
         }

         if (idx % 50 == 49)
         {
             printf("\n");
             thisPoint.y = thisPoint.y + 1;
             thisPoint.x = 0;
         }
         else
         {
             thisPoint.x = thisPoint.x + 1;
         }
     }];
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        ABManager *man = [ABManager sharedManager];
        int count = 0;
        BOOL ignoreKeypress = FALSE;
        while (TRUE)
        {
            if (CGEventSourceKeyState(kCGEventSourceStateCombinedSessionState,59) && !ignoreKeypress)
            {
                ignoreKeypress = TRUE;
                struct ABPoint p = man.charPos;
                p.y = p.y - 2;
                man.charPos = p;
            }
            else
            {
                ignoreKeypress = CGEventSourceKeyState(kCGEventSourceStateCombinedSessionState,59);

                if (count > 3)
                {
                    count = 0;
                    struct ABPoint p = man.charPos;
                    p.y = p.y + 1;
                    man.charPos = p;
                }
                else
                {
                    count = count + 1;
                }
            }

            if (man.charPos.y < -1 || man.charPos.y > 11 || man.shouldExit)
            {
                exit(1);
            }

            printf("\n\n\n\n\n");
            printf("\033[1;36m[\033[0m\033[1;30mHacky Bird\033[0m\033[1;36m]~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\033[0m\n");
            drawScreen(count);
            printf("\033[1;32m[\033[0m\033[1;31mScore: %li\033[0m\033[1;32m]~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\033[0m\n", (long)man.score);

            [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.0157];
        }

    }
}
```

ABManager.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h>

struct ABPoint {
    NSInteger x;
    NSInteger y;
};

@interface ABManager : NSObject
{

}

@property (nonatomic, readwrite) NSMutableArray *screen;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) NSMutableArray *obstacles;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) struct ABPoint charPos;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) NSInteger score;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) BOOL shouldExit;;

+ (id)sharedManager;

@end
```

ABManager.m

```
#import "ABManager.h"

@implementation ABManager
+ (id)sharedManager {
    static ABManager *sharedMyManager = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedMyManager = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedMyManager;
}

- (id)init
{
    if (self = [super init]) {

        self.screen = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (NSUInteger i=0; i < 600; i++)
        {
            [self.screen addObject:@" "];
        }

        self.score = 0;

        self.shouldExit = FALSE;

        struct ABPoint p;
        p.x = 5;
        p.y = 0;

        self.charPos = p;

        struct ABPoint o;
        o.x = 10;
        o.y = 5;

        struct ABPoint o2;
        o2.x = 30;
        o2.y = 5;

        self.obstacles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:@[[NSValue valueWithBytes:&o objCType:@encode(struct ABPoint)],[NSValue valueWithBytes:&o2 objCType:@encode(struct ABPoint)]]];
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```